# findIndex isn't returning the correct index

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, mongoose

findeIndex isn't returning the correct index in an express router function.

```
module.exports.nearestOffices = (req, res, next) => {
  Order.findById(req.params.idOrder).exec()
    .then(order => {
      return Promise.all([
        Promise.resolve(order),
        Office.find({'location': {$near: order.address_deliver.location, $maxDistance: maxDistance}}).sort({'timeToFinish': -1}).exec()
      ]);
    })
    .then(rslts => {
      let order = rslts[0];
      let offices = rslts[1];

      console.log('findIdex test: ', offices[0].stockProducts.findIndex(o => {
        console.log(o.product, '===', order.products[1].product);
        return o.product === order.products[1].product;
      }));

      return Promise.resolve('message');
    })
    .then(rslt => res.json(rslt))
    .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

The contents of the variables order and offices are:

```
//offices
[
 {
  "stockProducts": [
   {
    "product": "58c1a7f62193b95eec1765ad",
    "_id": "58c1a7f72193b95eec1765ae",
    "stock": 3
   },
   {
    "product": "58c1a8212193b95eec1765af",
    "_id": "58c1a8212193b95eec1765b0",
    "stock": 15
   },
   {
    "product": "58c1a84a2193b95eec1765b1",
    "_id": "58c1a84a2193b95eec1765b2",
    "stock": 20
   },
   {
    "product": "58c1a85f2193b95eec1765b3",
    "_id": "58c1a85f2193b95eec1765b4",
    "stock": 10
   }
  ]
 }
];

//order
{
 "products": [
  {
   "product": "58c1a84a2193b95eec1765b1",
   "price": 2,
   "cant": 5,
   "_id": "58c1c0e57b32c431d99a3969"
  },
  {
   "product": "58c1a8212193b95eec1765af",
   "price": 6,
   "cant": 2,
   "_id": "58c1c1107b32c431d99a396a"
  }
 ]
};
```

The output of the console.log is:

```
58c1a7f62193b95eec1765ad '===' 58c1a8212193b95eec1765af
58c1a8212193b95eec1765af '===' 58c1a8212193b95eec1765af
58c1a84a2193b95eec1765b1 '===' 58c1a8212193b95eec1765af
58c1a85f2193b95eec1765b3 '===' 58c1a8212193b95eec1765af

findIdex test:  -1
```

It should have return 1 in the second line, but I don't know why it doesn't, I tested this in another js file without the functions and it works just fine, I don't know why it doesn't work here.

Comment: Given you've used `===`, what are `typeof o.product` and `typeof order.products[1].product`?

Comment: @Bergi Both of them are strings. I did also try it with == and it doesn't work either, I've been on this like 3 hours.

Comment: maybe there's some white space or something, try trimming it

Comment: @Bergi I was wrong the typeof is object, I converted to string and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with mongoose, apparently it returns object values not string values. So the answer is:

```
console.log('findIdex test: ', offices[0].stockProducts.findIndex(o => {
  console.log(o.product.toString(), '===', order.products[1].product.toString());
   return o.product.toString() === order.products[1].product.toString();
}));
```